Patiloma- Where does it start?
Does Patiloma-(reverse order) start at #1. With ignorance ceasing/ no Volitonal formations etc.  Or, is it at #12. starting with cessation of Death, Birth ceases. etc. (I see both used).  Thank you.


I have heard that on one occasion, the Blessed One was staying at
Uruvelā on the bank of the Nerañjarā River at the root of the Bodhi
tree — the tree of awakening — newly awakened. And on that occasion he
sat at the root of the Bodhi tree for seven days in one session,
sensitive to the bliss of release. Then, with the passing of seven
days, after emerging from that concentration, in the second watch of
the night, he gave close attention to dependent co-arising in reverse
(paṭilomaṁ) order, thus:
When this isn't, that isn't. From the cessation of this comes the
cessation of that.
In other words:
From the cessation of ignorance comes the cessation of fabrications.
From the cessation of fabrications comes the cessation of
consciousness.
From the cessation of consciousness comes the cessation of
name-&-form.
From the cessation of name-&-form comes the cessation of the six sense
media.
From the cessation of the six sense media comes the cessation of
contact.
From the cessation of contact comes the cessation of feeling.
From the cessation of feeling comes the cessation of craving.
From the cessation of craving comes the cessation of clinging.
From the cessation of clinging comes the cessation of becoming.
From the cessation of becoming comes the cessation of birth.
From the cessation of birth, then aging-&-death, sorrow, lamentation,
pain, distress and despair all cease. Such is the cessation of this
entire mass of suffering & stress.
Then, on realizing the significance of that, the Blessed One on that
occasion exclaimed:
As phenomena grow clear
to the brahman — ardent, in jhāna —
his doubts all vanish
when he penetrates the ending
of requisite conditions.
Udana 1.2


Dependent Origination is a chain. The chain can not exist partially. It exists on the whole. For example - cessation of craving can not be achieved without cessation of ignorance. If any link is missing then the whole chain is missing. Therefore no matter where you start with cessation the whole chain must exist to some degree or the whole chain must vanish.
You can start with cessation of ignorance or cessation of cravings or cessation of attachments. One thing ceases the whole chain ceases.
